# Rear derailluer broken bolt

Tags: shimano, derailleur, replacement, bolt, hanger

I am trying to figure out the right part to replace this bolt that broke.  It went through the rear frame of bike into derailleur to a shimano dyna sys II unit.  I believe it is a hanger bolt but the ones I find online don't look exactly like it as it has a smooth portion (where the break is) that I don't see on the online.  Please see attached photoS and help.  So lost.

Thanks[image][image]

Comment: What frame is this? This is frame-specific. What type of bike is this?

Comment: its a Norco Killer B

Answer (score 7):

This looks like the Syntace 142 mm X-12 axis bolt that also serves as the derailleur hanger.

See https://www.pinkbike.com/news/syntace-142mm-12-norco-2011.html

Syntace catalogue (there are several lengths):
https://www.syntace.com/en_GB/products/liteville/accessories-spare-parts/630/x-12-screw-for-derailleur-hanger-28.5mm

[image]
Photo Syntace

In shops (be sure to buy the right length):
https://www.bike-components.de/en/Syntace/X-12-Derailleur-Hanger-Bolt-p24466/
https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/syntace-x-12-screw-for-derailleur-hanger-28.5mm-44555

Comment: I think you are 100% right.  looking at my frame and the bolt - the top threads do not engage in any thread on the bike frame.  I likely can just get a same length bolt to hang the derailleur from right?

Comment: @justlookingtogetout Yes, if it is Norco, it should be this one, see the pinkbike.com link. Check for the right length. You can measure the current bolt. Theoretically, you should have received a spare with your bike.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  ordered the part and will let you know how it goes.  Much appreciated.